# JPQL result list with possible second linked entity

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have two JPA entities, Customer and Address. Address has a link to Customer, but Customer has no link to Address. I know this sounds odd, though we can't change this at the moment.

In the database we have 100 customers, and 10 addresses linked to customers. I'd like to run a query that returns me a list of all 100 customers, and in a second column (if available) the address.

I'm able to do a query like this:

SELECT c, a from Customer c, Address a WHERE a.customerId = c.id;

This returns a List as I'd like to have, though only with the 10 customers actually having an address.

Is there a way in JPQL to get a list of the 100 customers, and in the second array position the address or null if none is present?

Answer (score 1):

You need a left outer join. Something like

```
SELECT Customer.id, Customer.name, Address.street, ... from Customer LEFT OUTER JOIN Address on address.customer_id = customer.id;
```

A description how to do with jpa you find here:

[How to create a JPA query with LEFT OUTER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202456/how-to-create-a-jpa-query-with-left-outer-join)

Regards,

Mike