# Oracle plus sign notation to hibernate join

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate

I have a where clause that has a condition as following:

```
a.system(+) = 'Test'
```

I am trying to convert it to hibernate using join

```
left join a where a.system = 'Test' or a.system = null
```

however this transformation only returns data when a.system = 'Test' or a.system = null which is not an outer join any more.

is there a correct solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

with left join you just have to put the join conditions. in the example below you will get all rows from table a with matching fields of table b, and null when there is no matching row in b.

```
select *
from a left join b on a.field = b.field and b.system = 'Test'
```

it will be clearer if you post a complete query.

Comment: i understand. but for using JPA, all relationships need to be defined in the @Table class. Since this is a join to a constant, I am confused how it should be done.

Comment: is system='Test' the only condition? please post the structure of the tables and a complete query, or explain which result you expect.

Comment: this seems to be your case [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202456/how-to-create-a-jpa-query-with-left-outer-join)

Answer (score 0):

To explain further, You always `join two tables` or a `result set` or a `view' that acts like a table. You have 'TEST' as a constant here. Your equivalent query in ANSI would look like :

`FROM table_a a`
 `LEFT JOIN table_b b`
  `ON  a.column = b.column`
  `AND b.system = 'TEST'`