# How to create JPA NamedQuery with LEFT JOIN

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, join

I have two entities: Car and Reservation. I would like to create named query with LEFT JOIN. I was trying to do this like it is described here [How to create JPA query with LEFT OUTER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202456/how-to-create-a-jpa-query-with-left-outer-join) but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea what is wrong in my query? I would like to show Cars which have NULL reservations. Anyway even with JOIN it does not work. After starting application I have an error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: Car.findAll
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:495) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

In principle I would like to achieve this query which in MySQL works

```
SELECT distinct * FROM car c LEFT JOIN reservation r ON c.id = r.car_id WHERE c.producer='producer' AND c.model='model' AND c.type='type' 
AND (r.date_of_rent < 'date1' AND r.date_of_return < 'date1') OR (r.date_of_rent > 'date2') OR r.date_of_rent IS NULL;
```

Car Entity

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Car.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Car c LEFT JOIN c.reservation r WHERE c.producer=:producer "
        + "AND c.type=:type AND c.dailyPrice=:dailyPrice")
public class Car implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String producer;
    private String model;
    private int seatsNumber;
    private String type;
    private String registrationNumber;
    private double dailyPrice;
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "car")
    private List<Reservation> reservations;
```

Reservation Entity

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Reservation implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne
    private Car car;
    private Date dateOfRent;
    private Date dateOfReturn;
```

Many thanks for help.

**UPDATE**

Problem solved. Query should look like this one

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Car.findAll", query = "SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Car c LEFT JOIN c.reservations r WHERE "
        + "c.type=:type AND c.dailyPrice<=:dailyPrice AND ((r.dateOfRent < :dateOfRent AND r.dateOfReturn < :dateOfRent) OR "
        + "(r.dateOfRent > :dateOfReturn) OR (r.dateOfRent IS NULL))")
public class Car implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String producer;
    private String model;
    private Integer seatsNumber;
    private String type;
    private String registrationNumber;
    private Double dailyPrice;
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "car")
    private List<Reservation> reservations;
```

Comment: Please, add to the question: Why do you need a left join?

Comment: "it doesn't work" ? What is that supposed to mean? You get an exception? It runs some SQL (that you don't post) but you get a different result to what you expect? Nothing happens at all?

Comment: I posted and error which I have with this query and which query I wouldlike to achieve.

Comment: @bartekms274 Better to add the part of stack trace with an error description. `Errors in named queries: Car.findAll` doesn't tell a lot. Also I have updated my answer with that error.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c FROM Car c LEFT JOIN c.reservation r WHERE c.producer=:producer "
        + "AND c.type=:type AND c.dailyPrice=:dailyPrice
```

There is an error in this query `c.reservation` need to be changed to `c.reservations`.

> I would like to show Cars which have NULL reservations.

You can't do it this way. Try to begin from this query:

```
select c from Car c where not exists (
    select r.id from Reservation r where r.car.id = c.id
)
```