# how to create jpql with left outer join

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql

I have for example 2 entities.
A entity (Mysql Table name="A")
B entity (Mysql Table name="B")
I want fetch data from A table where it is not in the B table.
I wrote sql and it is working.
    **SELECT * FROM A
      LEFT OUTER JOIN B
           ON A.id = B.a_id
     WHERE  B.id IS  null**

How to realize it with JPQL?

Comment: Not sure what your asking here. Are you asking for the entire setup needed in Java to get and store results in objects? Or how to translate that query into something that can be run from an entity manager? If the second point then at first glance it looks fine as it is.

Comment: yes,I want to translate it is to JPQL that can be run from an entity manager.

Comment: Then I don't see anything wrong with the query. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some kind of following structure:

```
Class EntityA
--------
long Id
Set<EntityB> Bs

Class EntityB
-------
long Id
EntityA A
```

I think following should work

```
SELECT a FROM EntityA a WHERE a.Bs IS EMPTY
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following website..It will help you

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying#Joining.2C_querying_on_a_OneToMany_relationship

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should work:

```
SELECT A FROM A a LEFT JOIN a.B b WHERE b.id = null;
```

This should join A with B on id leaving null where A can not match with B. Then it selects the rows from A where b.id is null. Seems like what you're looking for. Also checkout the following SOs: [How to make a JPA query with LEFT OUTER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750371/how-to-make-a-jpa-query-with-left-outer-join?lq=1)
And as done in the following: [How to create a JPA query with LEFT OUTER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202456/how-to-create-a-jpa-query-with-left-outer-join)

Let me know whether it worked out.

Comment: Well there is an ON operator in JPA 2.1 (but not in earlier versions), but there is no "SELECT *"

Answer (score 0):

You may use this command

SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.id NOT IN (SELECT B.id FROM B)

If you wan to use only join let me know

Comment: this is query is not true. because,he gives me ALL data from A table,but I  need the data from A table where it is not in B table

Comment: This query gives all from 'A' Where ID is not in 'B'. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Hi! I am using php mysql can you modify this query into your platform

Comment: @TomStone this query gives me all data from A (It is surprise for me ,too..because we added NOT IN condition)