# LEFT JOIN table mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.websystique.springmvc.model.AssetMakeMaster#0]

I have two entities are as follows:
1. AssetMaster
2. AssetMakeMaster

Above entities are mapped with tables. I want to use left join for above two entities and get the all the data from AssetMaster. Inner query is working fine for above entities but i want get the non matched values also. I have tried but not getting solution yet. Please anyone will give the solution for my problem.

I have tried the below query in mysql it gives me proper result but i want to get result from hibernate entities. Please give me solution for below query:

> SELECT * FROM fscassets.asset_master a left join
>   fscassets.asset_make_master b on a.make=b.id;
>
> ```
> /*  * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project
> Properties.  * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates 
> * and open the template in the editor.  */ package > > 
> /**  *  * @author Amol  */ 
> @Entity @Table(name = "asset_master")
> public class AssetMaster implements Serializable {
>
> @Id
> @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
> private Integer id;
>
> @Column(name = "make", nullable = false)
> private int make;
>
> @Column(name = "serialno", nullable = false)
> private String serialno;
>
> @Column(name = "specs", nullable = false)
> private String specs;
>
> @Column(name = "model", nullable = false)
> private String model;
>
> @Column(name = "quantity", nullable = false)
> private int quantity;
>
> @Column(name = "purchasedate", nullable = false)
> private String purchasedate;
>
> @Column(name = "created_on", nullable = false)
> private String createdOnDate;
>
> @Column(name = "remark", nullable = false)
> private String remark;
>
> @Column(name = "ipaddress", nullable = false)
> private String ipAddress;
>
>
> @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
> @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
> @JoinColumn(name = "make", updatable = false, insertable = false)
> private AssetMakeMaster assetMakeMasterdata;
>
> public AssetMakeMaster getAssetMakeMasterdata() {
>     return assetMakeMasterdata;
> }
>
> public void setAssetMakeMasterdata(AssetMakeMaster assetMakeMasterdata) {
>     this.assetMakeMasterdata = assetMakeMasterdata;
> }
>
>
>
> public Integer getId() {
>     return id;
> }
>
> public void setId(Integer id) {
>     this.id = id;
> }
>
>
> public String getCreatedOnDate() {
>     return createdOnDate;
> }
>
> public void setCreatedOnDate(String createdOnDate) {
>     this.createdOnDate = createdOnDate;
> }
>
> public String getIpAddress() {
>     return ipAddress;
> }
>
> public void setIpAddress(String ipAddress) {
>     this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
> }
>
>
> public int getMake() {
>     return make;
> }
>
> public void setMake(int make) {
>     this.make = make;
> }
>
> public String getSerialno() {
>     return serialno;
> }
>
> public void setSerialno(String serialno) {
>     this.serialno = serialno;
> }
>
> public String getSpecs() {
>     return specs;
> }
>
> public void setSpecs(String specs) {
>     this.specs = specs;
> }
>
> public String getModel() {
>     return model;
> }
>
> public void setModel(String model) {
>     this.model = model;
> }
>
> public int getQuantity() {
>     return quantity;
> }
>
> public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
>     this.quantity = quantity;
> }
>
> public String getPurchasedate() {
>     return purchasedate;
> }
>
> public void setPurchasedate(String purchasedate) {
>     this.purchasedate = purchasedate;
> }
>
>
> public String getRemark() {
>     return remark;
> }
>
> public void setRemark(String remark) {
>     this.remark = remark;
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> /*  * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project
> Properties.  * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates 
> * and open the template in the editor.  */ package > > 
> /**  *  * @author Amol  */
> ```
>
> @Entity
>      @Table(name = "asset_make_master")
>      public class AssetMakeMaster implements Serializable {
>
> ```
> @Id
> @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
> private Integer id;
>
> @NotEmpty
> @Column(name = "asset_make_name", unique = true, nullable = false)
> private String assetmakename;
>
> @Column(name = "assetgroup", nullable = false)
> private int groupid;
>
> @Column(name = "created_on", nullable = false)
> private String createdOnDate;
>
> @Column(name = "ipaddress", nullable = false)
> private String ipAddress;
>
>
> @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "assetMakeMasterdata")
> private List<AssetMaster> assetMakeMasters = new ArrayList<AssetMaster>();
>
> public List<AssetMaster> getAssetMakeMasters() {
>     return assetMakeMasters;
> }
>
> public void setAssetMakeMasters(List<AssetMaster> assetMakeMasters) {
>     this.assetMakeMasters = assetMakeMasters;
> }
> public Integer getId() {
>     return id;
> }
>
> public void setId(Integer id) {
>     this.id = id;
> }
>
> public String getAssetmakename() {
>     return assetmakename;
> }
>
> public void setAssetmakename(String assetmakename) {
>     this.assetmakename = assetmakename;
> }
>
> public int getGroupid() {
>     return groupid;
> }
>
> public void setGroupid(int groupid) {
>     this.groupid = groupid;
> }
>
> public String getCreatedOnDate() {
>     return createdOnDate;
> }
>
> public void setCreatedOnDate(String createdOnDate) {
>     this.createdOnDate = createdOnDate;
> }
>
> public String getIpAddress() {
>     return ipAddress;
> }
>
> public void setIpAddress(String ipAddress) {
>     this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
> }
>
>  }
> ```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a JPA query with LEFT OUTER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750371/how-to-make-a-jpa-query-with-left-outer-join)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use (*) in HQL query. If you want non matched values also then select that columns individually you will get values.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is a that you are fetching a AssetMaster that has the AssetMakeMaster id setted, but the AssetMakeMaster with the setted id is not in database anymore.